# C - printf() after scanf() not printing until next scanf()

Tags: c

I am trying to read first character in each line of the input and then based on the first character, determine which format the rest of the line is in. Then I use scanf() to read the values according to the command received.

```
char name[50];
int rating, ref;

int main() {
    int command;
    while (command = getchar()) {
        if (command == EOF || command == '\0') break;
        if (!processCommand(command)) break;
        printf("done processing, waiting for new command\n");
    }
}

char processCommand(int command) {
    switch (command) {
        case 'a':
            printf("starting\n");
            if (scanf(" %s %d %d\n", name, &rating, &ref) != 3) return 0;
            // SOME PROCESSING
            printf("done\n");
            break;
        default:
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The problem is that the output looks like this:

```
./program.out
a Test 5 12345
starting
a Testing 0 23456
done
done processing, waiting for new command
starting
```

Basically the `printf`s are not getting flushed to the stdout until the next `processCommand()` is called. I've tried all of these:

```
fflush(stdin);
while ( getchar() != '\n' );
fflush(stdout);
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

And none of them change anything in the output. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `command` should be an `int` since `getchar()` returns an `int`

Comment: @pzaenger Thanks for letting me know. I've updated the code. Unfortunately it did not affect the output.

Comment: `scanf(" %s %d %d\n"...` is suspicious.  That last `"\n"` may read in more than expected.

Comment: `getchar()` and `scanf()` don't play well together. You would be better off using `scanf()` exclusively, since your keyboard input is line buffered in any case. Also, read the man page for `scanf()`. You don't need `\n` in there.

Comment: @chux that fixed it. Can you add it as an answer, please?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage the problem is that the input format is different based on the first letter in the line. So I may need to do " %d" for lines starting with 'b' and " %s %d" for lines stating with 'c' and I can't do it all in one scanf() The `\n` was the cause of the problem after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"\n"` in `if (scanf(" %s %d %d\n"` prevents `scanf()` from returning until non-white-space is entered after the 2nd `int`.

`"\n"`  does not simply scan in a `'\n'`,  It scans in all white-space until another non-white-space occurs.  This usually involves a 2nd line of text as user input is line buffered.

Drop the `'\n'` at the end of `" %s %d %d\n"`.

Better yet, read using `fgets()` and drop using `scanf()`.  Use `sscanf()`, `strtok()`, `strtod()`, etc. instead.